# gcc ld error "libgcov.a(_gcov_merge_add.o) is referenced by DSO"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, rhel

Trying to compiler our code for code coverage using gcov. Getting following error:

> hidden symbol `__gcov_merge_add' in
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgcov.a(_gcov_merge_add.o) is
>   referenced by DSO /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable
>   section on output collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Following compiler options are newly added for gcov:

```
-O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage  -Xlinker -zmuldefs
```

and ld flags:

```
-fprofile-generate -fprofile-arcs
```

and linked with library `-lgcov`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for this issue is

- Compile with `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`
- Link with `-fprofile-arcs -lgcov`

I also got this same error when I was not using `-fprofile-arcs` while linking.

Answer (score 0):

We are able to enable the code coverage using simply `--coverage -O0` compiler options and finally linking with `-lgcov` for RHEL 6.* version.

However same doesnt with debian where we had to use `-O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Xlinker -zmuldefs` to make code coverage enabled binaries.